# Python: highlightthicknes=0 parameter in style configuration for tkinter.ttk Button with Image, has no result

Tags: python, themes, tkinter-button, ttkwidgets

[image]
A: tk.Button with image without highlightthicknes setting

[image]
B: tk.Button with image with highlightthicknes=0

[image]
C: ttk.Button with style.configure('custom.TButton', image=cross_image, highlightthickness=0)
The parameter "highlightthickness" in style configuration has no result.
Is there a way for ttk.Button with image, to be like "B"?

Tried in all themes in windows 10.